# How to check if an attribute has a presence validation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

Is there a way to know if an attribute has a validation? Something like following:

```
Model.attribute.has_presence_validation?
```

Comment: Interesting question (+1). What is the context for using this?

Comment: Thanks, in my case, will be to place "include_blank" to a dynamically generated select

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well not sure about simplest solution but I achieved this functionality with quite complexity. Maybe someone come up with some simpler solution. Here is the code which worked perfectly for me.

I get all the validations on a model, chose presence validations(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator) and then select all of their attributes and used include to check attribute(:your_attribute)presence in this array

```
Model.validators.collect{|validation| validation if validation.class==ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator}.compact.collect(&:attributes).flatten.include? :your_attribute
```

you can change compare statement

```
validation.class==ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator
```

to get all other types validation i.e uniqueness etc

Answer (score 3):

Combining some of the points in the other answers, I would have thought the following approach was most straightforward (Rails 4.2.7):

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates ... # Whatever your validation are

  def self.presence_required_attrs
    validators.select do |v|
      v.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator)
    end.map(&:attributes).flatten
  end
end
```

It's then as easy as:

```
Model.presence_required_attrs.include?(:my_attribute)
```

Edit:

More comprehensive solution I think is just having a helper or controller method:

```
def validated_attrs_for(model, validation)
    if validation.is_a?(String) || validation.is_a?(Symbol)
      klass = 'ActiveRecord::Validations::' \
              "#{validation.to_s.camelize}Validator"
      validation = klass.constantize
    end
    model.validators
         .select { |v| v.is_a?(validation) }
         .map(&:attributes)
         .flatten
end
```

Used:

```
validated_attrs_for(Model, :presence).include?(:my_attribute)
```

Just double check that the various validators (:presence, :uniqueness, etc.) correctly correspond to the appropriate Validator class -- I'm pretty sure they do, but haven't looked recently.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the following code is working (it is basically checking if any validator for given field is an instance of the presence validator):

```
MyModel.validators_on(:my_attribute).any?{|validator| validator.kind_of?(ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator)}
```